# Changing the size of an img container without changing the image size?

Tags: image, tumblr, css

Here's an example of my markup:

```
<li class="tumblr_post tumblr_photo_post">
    <img class="tumblr_photo" alt="Testing photo post" src="http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_li5e4zfgrd1qi4tmio1_400.png">
    <div class="tumblr_caption">
        <p>Testing photo post</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I'd like to change the size of the image's container without changing the image's size. As it's directly in the flow as an `img`, how can I do this?

Comment: Update: The use of javascript to encase the img tag in a div is perfectly fine. From there I can adjust the div's style so that it fits with my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your image is not contained into a div container like you are doing with the video on top.

Try to use the following jQuery code to add the img into a div container. You will have to add the jQuery library to your page of course.

```
$('.tumblr_photo').wrap('<div class="somename" />');
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to do some JavaScript manipulations after the image is loaded?

Comment: I'm with moleculezz on this one, based on the markup you've got, the only way to stretch it would be to add javascript manipulation after the image has loaded :)

Comment: Definitely possible. I just don't know how :)

Comment: I modified my answer to include a solution using the jQuery wrap function.